# Why dialog. destroy () does not immediately close the filerequester

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk

In this script, where is the error?
Why dialog. destroy () does not immediately close the filerequester
but only closes it after 5 seconds: instruction time. sleep (5) to line 41?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


import sys, os, time


class finestra(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Titolo")
        self.set_default_size(100, 100)

    def selFile(self):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Seleziona un file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
             Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL))

        dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)

        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            file_path = dialog.get_filename()
            return file_path
            dialog.destroy()

        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Non è stato selezionato alcun file")
            dialog.destroy()

win = finestra()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()

ff=win.selFile()
print(ff)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: No one speaks?
Yes, maybe the problem is trivial but for me it's serious!

Answer (score 0):

In the condition, `if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:`, you are returning before destroying the dialog. Due to which, the statement `dialog.destroy()` has no effect.